# MySQL connection reuse problem

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reuse mysql connection. Hence I have a global variable in databasemanager.php class   that returns a connection.

The problem is somehow on one particular page mysql is executing prior query as well.

Looks like there is some leftover query in connection object that gets executed if same connection is being reused . Is it possible ? how to solve  this ..

```
 function getDBConnection(){
   global $conn;
   if (!empty($conn)){
// echo $conn ;
    return $conn;
   }
   $conn =  mysql_connect($GLOBALS['HOSTNAME'],$GLOBALS['DBUSER'],$GLOBALS['DBPASS']);

    if (!$conn) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['DBNAME'],$conn);
    return $conn;
```

}

This how code lookslike

Comment: We need to see how you connected (what function and what params).
Also, do you reuse the connection over requests or in the same request?

Comment: Have you got a particular reason for wanting to reuse MySQL connections? They are usually quite lightweight so there isn't much sense in trying to reuse them (unless you plan to have huge loads or run on restricted hardware).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [mysql_pconnect](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-pconnect)?

According to the documentation:

> mysql_pconnect() acts very much like
> mysql_connect() with two major
> differences.
>
> First, when connecting, the function
> would first try to find a (persistent)
> link that's already open with the same
> host, username and password. If one is
> found, an identifier for it will be
> returned instead of opening a new
> connection.
>
> Second, the connection to the SQL
> server will not be closed when the
> execution of the script ends. Instead,
> the link will remain open for future
> use (mysql_close() will not close
> links established by
> mysql_pconnect()).